# Postix : no incoming mails (in certain circumstances only)

Tags: email, smtp, imap, postfix-mta

I have a mail server based on Postfix + Dovecot (IMAP) on a CentOS 5.6, everything works, but I don't receive emails, and I get no notification of non-delivery, they just never show up.

About the DNS, the MX (mail.example.net) are just ok, no problem there. 
I can telnet both Postfix (port 25) and Dovecot (port 143) with no troubles, from localhost as well as from the public IP. I have a Roundcube webmail that works too, I can connect on it, send emails, see my folders, etc.
The problems come when receiving emails, there are simply not received. For example, I send a test email from my gmail account, it never shows up. A strange thing is that instead, if I telnet the Postfix of another server and send an email to contact@example.net, it is received o.O

In addition i can say that if i monitor `/var/log/maillog`, nothing is coming when someone sends me an email, but it works using telnet as explained above.

Where the problem could be?

Thank you

fabien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check the logs of a SENDING system where the connection doesn't work. or wait a few days for the bounce of your gmail test. there is not much you can do on the receiving side. could be a routing issue that only affects some networks (routing to your MTA or DNS servers). if you changed your mx records recently, remember that it takes some time until all DNS caches are up-to-date

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gryphius. Now I suspect too that this comes from the slow DNS propagation, the new MX zone has been added something like 24h ago now. Let's wait and see :>